# Switching to left-handed mouse leaves touchpad taps reversed

Tags: 15.04, touchpad

Ubuntu 15.04, when I set the mouse settings to left handed, a peripheral mouse works perfectly, however, tap settings on my touchpad are reversed (single finger tap triggers secondary click, double finger tap triggers primary click).

How can I fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will swap the behavior of the single tap with the behavior of the double tap  in the current session:

```
synclient TapButton1=3; synclient TapButton2=1
```

To make the changes permanent, add the commands to `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` after the line `post-start script`:

```
post-start script
    synclient TapButton1=3
    synclient TapButton2=1
    sleep 5
    clear > /dev/tty7
end script
```